# best way to animate arc in a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I'm looking at the best / most efficient way to create several circles (arc) on a canvas.

I've seen that to create multiple circles you do something similar to (http://webdesign.about.com/od/html5tutorials/a/draw-circles-on-html5-canvas.htm)

```
context.arc(x1,y,radius,0,Math.PI,true);
context.stroke();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x2,y,radius,0,Math.PI,false);
context.stroke();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x3,y,radius,0,Math.PI,true);
context.stroke();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x4,y,radius,0,Math.PI,false);
context.stroke();
```

What I'm trying to do is have 3 or 4 circles in increasing size that I loop through, animating the color of each, animate from one color and back to its original color then move to the next circle and repeat. 
I'm just thinking, could I have an id for each circle, or have the circles in an array/object which I loop through?

Like so

```
circles = {
    circle1 : '',
    circle2 : '',
    circle3 : ''
}
```

In the first example, I don't see how I would get hold of each circle to do something with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Best and most efficient" very much depends on your situation.

- Fastest drawing
- Least memory used
- Fewest redraws
- Many other possibilities!

It is fairly efficient to do as you suggest and put your circle definitions in an array and then use that array to draw your circles.

Here's one example using an array of circle definitions to animate color-changing concentric circles.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/R5D7M/

[image]

Example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        var cx=150;
        var cy=150;
        var PI2=Math.PI*2;
        var radius=0;

        // these are the circle definitions kept in an array
        // each definition holds: radius, color, stroke-width
        var circles=[];

        // add some test circles
        addCircle(15,"red");
        addCircle(15,"green");
        addCircle(15,"blue");
        addCircle(15,"purple");
        addCircle(15,"lightblue");
        addCircle(15,"lightgreen");
        addCircle(15,"maroon");
        var targetIndex=0;


        function addCircle(lineWidth,color){
            if(radius==0){
                radius=lineWidth/2;
            }else{
                radius+=lineWidth;
            }
            circles.push({radius:radius,color:color,width:lineWidth});
        }


        // draw 1 circle based on its definition
        // "color" specifies the alternate color for the circle
        function drawCircle(circle,color){
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(cx,cy,circle.radius,0,PI2);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.lineWidth=circle.width;
                ctx.strokeStyle=color;
                ctx.stroke();
        }


        // animate at about 1 frame-per-second
        var fps = 1;
        function animate() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                // request another animation loop
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                // Drawing code goes here
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
                    var circle=circles[i];
                    var color=circle.color;
                    if(i==targetIndex){ color="gold"; }
                    drawCircle(circles[i],color);
                }
                // target the next circle
                if(targetIndex++ > circles.length){ targetIndex=0; }
            }, 1000 / fps);
        }

        // start!
        animate();        

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Each stroked circle will animate to gold color</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need to make an array of circles (At somepoint they will be a centipede like int he arcade game centipede) I want to draw it on the canvas and then move it from the top of the canvas down the screen and if it runs into another circle then it randomly goes a different direction. Like in centipede.

Comment: This question/answer does not direct relate to your centipede game.  But these concepts of this answer might be used in your game: the circles[] array to store circle definitions, the addCircle() and drawCircle() functions to create and draw circles in a reusable way, the requestAnimationFrame() to efficiently run your animation loop (with different animation code of course).  So design and code up the basics of your game...ask new Stackoverflow questions if you run into problems.  Good luck with your game!